# Fatal: Unable to attach to remote geth: dial unix ./.ethereum/geth.ipc: connect: connection refused

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

I am trying to attach geth.ipc by using following command.

```
geth attach ./.ethereum/geth.ipc
```

But getting below error.

> Fatal: Unable to attach to remote geth: dial unix
>   ./.ethereum/geth.ipc: connect: connection refused

Note : geth.ipc file exists that i checked using `sudo find -name *.ipc` command and it returns me `./.ethereum/geth.ipc` and it was working till yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was getting this error because i had to run start geth before attaching the `ipc` file.So before `geth attach ./.ethereum/geth.ipc` command i had to run

```
sudo geth --rpcapi eth,web3,personal --rpc --networkid=15
```

Comment: this didnt work for me